# proving several qualities of a given function

Tags: calculus, continuity, functional-inequalities

I'm really not sure regarding this question. would like your help if possible.

given the function:

$  f(n) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{e^x-1}{x},  & \text{if $x \neq0$ } \\
1 & \text{if $x=0$ }
\end{cases}
$

a) Prove for every $x\neq0$ $e^x(x-1)+1>0.$

b) Prove that $f$ in continuous in R.

c) Use the above to prove that $f$ is monotonously increasing in R.

d) Prove that every $c>0$ has a solution for $f(x)=c.$

What i did:

a) I used it as a function and tried to show that the limit is always positive, when $x \to\infty$ and $x\to\infty$ while showing that it doesn't hold for $x=0.$

b) Using the limits of a) to show continuity, with the exception of $x=0,$ which I didn't know how to prove continuous in regards to the other part of the function.

c) Didn't know how to prove it.

d)using the above, I tried to use the intermediate value theorem, by showing that since the function is continuous, then there most exist a $c$ so that $f(x)=c.$ I didn't know how to prove that only for $c>0.$

Please show me the right way to do it, as I'm sure that I've done too many errors, and I don't know how to do it correctly.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

i will start with b 
to be continuous in R
we see that (e^x+1)/x continuous in R{0}
but f continuous in 0 because
f(0)=1
lim (e^x+1)/x when x---->0 =1
then c we have to Find derivative 
f`(x)= (e^x)/(x^2) and =0 if  x=0
f'>(or=0) then f is monotonously increasing
d-
Since the function is always increasing
Each horizontal line will be offset by y = c
At only one point is the solution
i am very happy becaus i help you and if you found questoin ask me and i will tey in (a)

Comment: thank you very much for your help.

how would you approach to solving the inequality $e^x(x-1)+1>0$ for every $x \neq 0$? 

thank again

Comment: ok thank you i will try with a  e^x+1/(x-1)>0 if (x-1)>0 and  e^x+1/(x-1)<0 if (x-1)<0  and x isnt 0 then  let start with e^x+1/(x-1)>0 if (x)>1  we can see e^x>1 and 1/(x-1)>1 then e^x+1/(x-1)>1>0 let we see in the second e^x+1/(x-1)<0 if (x)<1  we can see e^x<1 and 1/(x-1)<1 then e^x+1/(x-1)<0 thene^x+1/(x-1)>0 i hope i can help you

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.